# Large tables with numpy arrays as indices

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to store a large table. But my indices are not integers (say numpy arrays).

If integers, I can use arrays. If strings, i can use dictionaries.

For numpy arrays, how can I store my table with an inbuilt function? Is there any such function.

In concise, I need to store real numbers T(x, y), where x and y are tuples.

Comment: Tuples (and integers) can be dictionary keys too.

Comment: Sorry @jonrsharpe, my mistake.